# What are the differences between stage and stageros?

Tags: simulation, stage, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using stage, diamondback has 2 executables at */opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_stage/stage/bin* - stage and stageros. How are these two different, particularly in the usage ? Using these two in simple environments shows no differences.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11041/what-are-the-differences-between-stage-and-stageros-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-08-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hmm good question. There are 2 stage executable files in the stage bin directory. stage and stageros.

stage is the one compiled from the original stage files. It can be used as the original stage simulator if the libraries are linked correctly. (By default the libraries are not linked for stage, the stage library has to be added to ldconfig)

However, stage does not provide the interface to ros. So if you use stage, the simulation data will not be available to ros although it will probably still work with player.

stageros on the other hand makes a portion of the stage interface available to ROS.
It published the following topics to the ros interface, so that it would work with nodes written for ROS.

/base_pose_ground_truth

/base_scan

/clock

/cmd_vel

/odom

/tf

So if you want to run simulation in ros, you gotta use the stageros instead of stage; in order for ros to interpret the simulation data.

---

Originally posted by [Zack](https://answers.ros.org/users/949/zack/) with karma: 216 on 2011-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-03**:
@Zack : One more observation to confirm to your answer; stageros needs an instance of roscore, stage can function without roscore.

**Comment by [Zack](https://answers.ros.org/users/949/zack/) on 2011-08-29**:
simulations in ros.

**Comment by [Zack](https://answers.ros.org/users/949/zack/) on 2011-08-29**:
Nope, there's only one excutable for gazebo. stage is useful for 2D simulations. It's easier to setup and is good for simple model. However for more complex models, gazebo would be able to model them more accurately. You can take a look at the provided launch files to get an idea of how to launch

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-08-29**:
@Zack : Thank you ! I am not really into gazebo - but do we have a similar situation there too ? gazebo and gazeboros (?) ?